# Excel UDF gets called twice, returns different values each time

Tags: excel, vba, match, user-defined-functions

I am trying to find a value at a given date in a table.  The table headings are the months and the items underneath are the values to lookup.  I am using the Application.Match function to find the column with the date in it.  The strange thing is that the function is always called twice. The first time through, col returns "empty".  The second time through it returns the correct column, but I cannot see any difference in the calls to the Match function.  The function is as follows:

```
Function find_needed(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal project As String, _
                     ByVal mon As Date, ByVal eng_type As Integer) As String

Dim col As Variant
Dim dd As Double
On Error GoTo duh

find_needed = 0
dd = CDbl(mon)
Debug.Print (rng.Address)
Debug.Print (dd)
col = Application.Match(dd, rng, 0)
If IsError(col) Or col = xlErrNA Then
   MsgBox "Error"
Else
    If col <> 0 Then
       find_needed = Worksheets(project).Cells(eng_type + 3, col).Value
    End If
End If
GoTo miss
duh:
    MsgBox "Error:" & Err.Description
miss:
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"The strange thing is that the function is always called twice"* - how do you know it's being called twice?

Comment: Can you attach a pic to show the layout, could help for testing the udf

Comment: I tried your UDF in a worksheet cell and it worked just fine.  Are you using it in a cell or in a sub??

Comment: `find_needed = Worksheets(project).Cells(eng_type + 3, col).Value` in the event you have multiple workbooks open and the UDF isn't in the activeworkbook, it will try to access the named sheet in the activeworkbook.  I would tag on `Thisworkbook` to be sure.

Comment: Is there any difference in the arguments between the two calls which give different results?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I am testing it by putting using it in a cell and calling it that way though it will finally be called from another UDF which adds the values from every sheet.  @dwirony.  I see  it is being called twice because the debug prints are being called twice and I can see the number in the cell being first =0 and then the correct number.

Comment: @Tim Williams I do not call it twice.  I call it by pressing enter on the formula inside the cell and see that it is called twice.

Comment: The way I call it is: =find_needed(LUISA!$3:$3, "LUISA", $Q$24,3)

Comment: I don't think it unusual for a UDF to be called more than once, maybe due to how Excel works out the calculation tree.   See  - http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the link.  This has lots of information.  I  can understand why it may be called twice, what I cannot understand is why the call to Application.Match returns different results for each call. Its as if in the first call it did not finish in time and gives 0, when the second call works.

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not receive an answer I have recoded the routine to perform the match using standard Excel and to read this using using VBA.  This works as expected. I was worried that the calling routine would be given the wrong answer after the first call and calculate the wrong result.